# How to get client machine java-version using java,javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Again the same question -
Is it possible to get the client machine java version using javascript java and jsp?

Any sample code wil be much useful.

Thanks -
Haan

Comment: *"... this shows only my java version installed and not the client machine java-version ..."* - I think you are mistaken.  The JS in that page is executed on the user's browser ...

Comment: I've checked your edit history. You will get the same values for "server" and "client" when the webserver runs at physically the same machine as the webclient(webbrowser). Have you taken this into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how Oracle's [deployJava.js](http://java.com/js/deployJava.js) does it.

Answer (score 0):

look http://javatester.org/version.html